# Spring Web: How to transfer many multipart file and JSON to @RestController

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, httprequest, multipartform-data

I have challenge to create spring controller which consumes array of MultipartFile and JSON.

I've already done controller for JSON and **one** Multipart file:

Controller:

```
@PostMapping("/upload")
@ApiOperation("Загрузить новый файл")
@ResponseBody
public Map uploadFile(@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file,
                      @RequestPart(required = false) JsonObject json) throws IOException {
    UUID fileId = fileService.save(file);
    UUID jsond = jsonService.save(json);

    return ImmutableMap.of("fileId", fileId, "jsond", jsond );
}
```

Config file:

```
@Component
public class JsonConventerConfig extends AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter {

    protected JsonConventerConfig(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        super(objectMapper, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canWrite(Class<?> clazz, MediaType mediaType) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canWrite(Type type, Class<?> clazz, MediaType mediaType) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean canWrite(MediaType mediaType) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

But I have no idea how to adapt my controller for array with MultipartFile.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved by simply adding an array to @RequestPart.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/file")
@ApiOperation("Загрузить новый файл")
@ResponseBody
public Set<UUID> uploadFile(@RequestPart MultipartFile[] files,
                            @RequestPart(required = false) Document document) throws IOException
```

As it turned out swagger does not support multipart requests, so I were getting exception during testing.